# what's wrong with my tensorflow after i install pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow

i'm new to python so the question might seem to be stupid.Before i install pandas ,everything is ok. after i install it ,i try

```
>>>import tensorflow

usage: [-h] [--sum] N [N ...]
: error: the following arguments are required: N
```

in IDLE:

```
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
import tensorflow
File "C:\Users\35963\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-
packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import *
File "C:\Users\35963\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-
packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 77, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.estimator import estimator_lib as estimator
File "C:\Users\35963\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-
packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator_lib.py", line 24, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.estimator.inputs import inputs
File "C:\Users\35963\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-
packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\inputs\inputs.py", line 22, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.estimator.inputs.numpy_io import numpy_input_fn
File "C:\Users\35963\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-
packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\inputs\numpy_io.py", line 22, in 
<module>
from tensorflow.python.estimator.inputs.queues import feeding_functions
File "C:\Users\35963\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-
packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\inputs\queues\feeding_functions.py", 
line 40, in <module>
import pandas as pd
File "C:\Users\35963\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-
packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
plot_params = pandas.plotting._style._Options(deprecated=True)
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'plotting'
```

so is it means my tensorflow and pandas are incompatible?:(

i install them using pip .  their version: python3.5.2,tensorflow (1.2.1),pandas (0.20.3)

Comment: I found this possibly-related issue: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16536